# Why is this not displaying my background image title.png?

Tags: java, image, background, textures, libgdx

apologies in advance for the very newbie question, currently trying to learn libGDX, every tutorial suggests this should work, its correctly displaying the text button in the centre of the screen however it isnt showing the background image title.png.

ive played around with it quite a bit to try and get it to work with no luck, any help you can give me would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class MainMenu implements Screen {

    ZebraGems game;
    Stage stage;
    BitmapFont font;
    BitmapFont blackfont;
    TextureAtlas atlas;
    Skin skin;
    SpriteBatch batch;
    TextButton button;
    Texture titleTexture;
    Sprite titleSprite;

    public MainMenu(ZebraGems game){
        this.game = game;
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        stage.act(delta);

        batch.begin();
        titleSprite.draw(batch);
        stage.draw();
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        if (stage == null);
        stage = new Stage (width, height, true);
        stage.clear();

        titleTexture = new Texture("data/title.png");

        titleSprite = new Sprite(titleTexture);
        titleSprite.setColor(1,1,1,0);
        titleSprite.setSize(480, 800);
        titleSprite.setPosition (0, 0);

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        TextButtonStyle style = new TextButtonStyle();
        style.up = skin.getDrawable("play");
        style.down = skin.getDrawable("playpressed");
        style.font = blackfont;

        button = new TextButton("", style);
        button.setWidth(213);
        button.setHeight(94);
        button.setX(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() /2 - button.getWidth() /2);
        button.setY(Gdx.graphics.getHeight() /2 - button.getHeight() /2);

        stage.addActor(button);
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {

        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        atlas = new TextureAtlas("data/playButton.pack");
        skin = new Skin();
        skin.addRegions(atlas);

        blackfont = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("data/blackfont.fnt"));
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        skin.dispose();
        atlas.dispose();
        stage.dispose();
        blackfont.dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `stage.draw()` out of the `batch.begin()` and `batch.end()`.

Furthermore in case you are using the latest nighty build of libgdx, you should add `stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true)` to your `resize(...)` method.

Furthermore you are doing this `titleSprite.setColor(1,1,1,0)` which sets the alpha of the background sprite to 0 which means 100% transparent = invisible.

Do this instead: `titleSprite.setColor(1,1,1,1)`.

In total your render should look like this:

```
batch.begin();
titleSprite.draw(batch);
batch.end();

stage.act(delta);
stage.draw();
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but when i remove stage.draw() it stops displaying the text button and doesnt display the background either!

Comment: I didn't tell you to remove it completely, but don't call it inside of the batch begin/end...

Comment: also, you shouldn't be creating a new Stage in every resize() call. Create it once, and within the resize() method just adapt the viewport with setViewport(...). So you by the way don't even need your own SpriteBatch anymore since the stage has one itself...

Comment: ah sorry, where should i move it? i tried a couple of places i thought should work with no luck.

Comment: I edited my answer, because there was one more error. Furthermore: move the stage.draw call just right after stage.act.

Comment: excellent thanks guys. It displays the background correctly now! however the text button is now missing (i assume its now hidden behind the title.png and i need to figure out how to make sure the button is in the foreground?)

Comment: thanks very much noone (and evident), its working correctly now and believe it or not ive actually learned some valuable lessons about programming/libGDX sorting this out with your valuable help! this is the first time ive used stackoverflow, is there some way i can give you recognition for your help? a thumbs up or +1 or whatever? :)

Comment: Left to my answer there are some triangle signs, if you click on the one pointing upwards, it will be an upvote. There will also be a little "check sign" appearing when you move the mouse in this area to mark the answer as "correct", which you should do, so it won't be listed as "unanswered" anymore.